# Create an optimal route on the map for a set of co-ordinates

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, location

I have a set a of co-ordinates which i will extract from the address of a location.
Now, my task is to generate an optimal path for these points.
How can i achieve this task ? I have seen examples for generating routes for two points. but i cant imagine it on a larger scale when there are multiple destinations to be covered.
I am using this feature for an android application.

Comment: You need to study 'The travelling salesman' algorithm/problem. This is non-trivial. (Not sure of US spelling for 'travelling', might be just one 'l')

Comment: Android does not use the Google Maps API V3. (tag removed)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to visit them in a specific sequence, the problem can be reduced to solving the path for two points: Simply solve the problem the same way using adjacent pairs of coordinates, then stitch the path together connecting starting points to end points.

If you have to visit them in any order and optimise the distance travelled, then you are solving the [traveling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) that is in fact, NP-Hard. The only exact solution is to try out all permutations, it is in fact, similar to the previous case, however will consume far too much time to be practice for large sets of points. First off, solve the shortest path for every pair of points, retaining only the distance in order to save memory. This will take n(n-1)/2 operations. Next, generate every permutation of your set of coordinates and calculate the path associated with them using the previously calculated data. The permutation (and the path associated with it) with the least distance will be your optimal sequence. Generate the path again using the method mentioned in the first paragraph.

The first step of the algorithm may seem to be time consuming, but it is in fact the second step that is non-polynomial. There are non-exact solutions that run faster, but they vary in their reliability. You will have to use trial and error to decide if they suit your application.

Comment: I have been analysing many TSP solutions online. but i am not able to distinguish which one is favourable for me. [TSP Solver](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-tsp-solver/) and [another one](http://www.nicecode.eu/a-java-tsp-solver-which-uses-google-maps-api/) another one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "pathfinding" or "routing" problem:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding

And it is often faced with Dijikstra's algorithm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

or with its generalization known as "A* algorithm":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-star_algorithm

In the latest years, this stuff have evolved into the "contraction hierarchies" algorithm:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_hierarchies

that is much faster and more efficient.

There are a few pathfinding/routing engine out there. The best one is arguably the Open Source Routing Machine:

http://project-osrm.org/

You can find a few more engines out there. Just Google around for "map routing" or "pathfinding".

Usually, the engine is a (RESTful) web service you have to access through the Net, not a library you can embed in your Java/Android project.

Comment: i was looking for a TSP solver in java which i could use in my project. But i could hardly find one. I also studied the [vehicle routing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem)
but i could not find its implementations. Still googling, i hope i will get somewhere soon.
Also i am confused as to which approach to follow.